# Ubuntu not enough space on AWS EC2

Tags: 12.04, amazon-ec2

I have 25GB volume on EC2. OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I can connect to it, but cannot even write 1KB. I tried to delete some files and write again - the same result - not enough space.

I tried to check free space and got this error.

```
df -h
df: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
```

Then I tried to get directory sizes. It seems that only 13GB from 25GB is full:

```
du -h --max-depth=1
18M     ./boot
16K     ./lost+found
4.0K    ./tmp
83M     ./lib
192K    ./home
8.7M    ./bin
4.0K    ./selinux
4.0K    ./opt
100K    ./root
8.0K    ./dev
du: cannot access `./proc/1312/task/1312/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/1312/task/1312/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/1312/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/1312/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       ./proc
7.9M    ./sbin
434M    ./usr
172K    ./run
13G     ./var
0       ./sys
4.0K    ./srv
4.0K    ./mnt
4.0K    ./lib64
4.0K    ./media
5.8M    ./etc
13G     .
```

Mounts

```
mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1912272k,nr_inodes=478068,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=768100k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-label/cloudimg-rootfs on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,relatime)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have edited `/etc/fstab` manually or you have mounted/unmounted a device which didn't reflect in `/etc/fstab` and it doesn't resemble `/proc/mounts` entries.

Do a `grep -v rootfs /proc/mounts` to see the difference. Update the `/etc/fstab` accordingly and try the mount or `df -h` command.

If that didn't do the trick then try `grep -v rootfs /proc/mounts > /etc/mtab`.

If you still get a disk space issue then you may need to reboot.

Comment: _grep -v rootfs /proc/mounts > /etc/mtab_ for me and _df: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory_ issue resolved also tried to reboot no issue till now.